# what is wrong in this code?

Tags: php, javascript, parameter-passing

I have to use this piece of code to save some values in table when page loads. The function to search values is in php. I have to use those values in script. I am trying this way but its not working.

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
      var msg_top = new array();
      msg_top = "<"+"?php echo searchResults('windows');"+"?"+">";
      var url = "msg2_mysql.php"
    var request = null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
             {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
               request=new XMLHttpRequest();
             }
          else
             {// code for IE6, IE5
               request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
             if (request.readyState == 4) {
                     if (request.status == 200) {
                         alert('POST');
                     } else {
                          alert(request.status); //
                     }
                    }
                   }
      request.send("msg_top=" + encodeURIComponent(msg_top).replace(/%20/g, '+'));
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: @XCeptable - You cannot pass a PHP SimplexmlElement object to JavaScript, JavaScript don't understand

Comment: @ ajreal, I have seen in many forums they are referring

Comment: @xil3, I edited the code & added detail.

Comment: I edited code. Its not a syntax error now. Error is $ not defined

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: p.s. submitting PHP file names and PHP source code from the client to the server, to be run on the server, is probably the worst idea that I've ever heard. It's also one of the most insecure. Please don't do it like this. I'd offer suggestions, but you give us no insight into what it is you're actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            //alert('POST');
    } else {
        alert(request.status); // fails here
    }}
```

Should probably be something like:

```
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
                //alert('POST');
        } else {
            alert(request.status); // fails here
        }
    }
}
```

If you pay proper attention to your indentation, you'll notice you never end the anonymous function you create at:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
```

Comment: You still don't close your anonynous function which you create here:$(document).ready(function() {

Comment: I closed that, actually other function starting within 1st confuses where to close which.